# Should sqlcmd and sqlcmd-mode be separate tags?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I feel like question relating to sqlcmd.exe, (ie command line tags, setting other editors, using with third party terminal enhancements) belong in a separate category than those related to "SQLCMD Mode" syntax in SSDT and SSMS.

As an example [My question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91312/how-do-i-get-ssms-to-use-the-relative-path-of-the-current-script-with-r-in-sqlc/91315#91315) is all about sqlcmdmode and nothing to do with sqlcmd.exe. However, [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/sql-server-command-line-usage-is-it-possible/75452#75452) has nothing to do with sqlcmdmode, and very specific to sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: Can you post some example questions where the distinction would have been beneficial?